# Rename duplicated file with applescript based on excel/txt list

Tags: excel, applescript

I am having some issues with making a duplicating and renaming a list of files based on an excel file.

In the excel file in column 1 there is the original name. In column 2 I put in the new name.
There is a base folder with a lot of images, only the images in the excel file should be duplicated and renamed.

It is important that the duplicating and the renaming is done at once, because it is possible that the same base file is needed more than once in the destination file.

Tried a lot with renaming, but I only get the copying working.

```js
set listFile to POSIX path of (choose file)
set dataList to paragraphs of (read listFile as «class utf8»)

tell application "Finder"
    
    set ImageFile to "Macintosh HD:Users:joostjenneskens:Pictures:Base"
    
    set theFolder to "Macintosh HD:Users:joostjenneskens:Pictures:Destination"
    
    repeat with thisFileName in dataList
        
        with timeout of 1200 seconds
            
            duplicate (files of folder ImageFile whose name starts with (thisFileName as text)) to theFolder with replacing and exact copy
            
        end timeout
        
    end repeat
    
end tell
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

rename the duplicate values in excel or txt file format.

Answer (score 0):

In your script, there is nothing about the destination file names. I assume every line in tour table contains a pair of tab-separated filenames
You should extract every items's columns with something like this :

```
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {tab} -- or ";" for CSV
copy (every text item of thisFileName) to {sourceFileName, destinationFileName}
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {} -- dirty reset (you should save/restore the previous settings)
```

then you can use the two variables **sourceFileName** and **destinationFileName**
and compute the full paths  sourceFullPathName and destFullPathName

I would try this for the copy action

```
log "Copying" & space & sourceFileName & " to " &  destinationFileName
do shell script "cp" & space & quoted form of posix path of sourceFullPathName & space & quoted form of posix path of destFullPathName
```

type "man cp" in your terminal to select suitable options (with "cp -v")
BTW it could be possible to create links or aliases  with "ln" instead of "cp"

the terms

```
   (files of folder ImageFile whose name starts with (thisFileName as text))
```

should return a list of source files…
With the "cp" mode you should add a nested loop to copy them, but how to figure out what's the destination name ?

hope this could help…